Can't import @tensorflow, @mediapipe libraries in JS
I'm trying to build a chrome extension that uses the pre-built tensorflowjs face landmark detection model. I'm having trouble importing the models for usage. I've tried following the documentation for both the mediapipe and tfjs solutions exactly:
tfjs solution
mediapipe solution
However, when I try to import the libraries like the example given below,
import '@mediapipe/face_mesh';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
// Register WebGL backend.
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl';
import * as faceLandmarksDetection from '@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection';

I get this kind of error for each import statement: Failed to resolve module specifier "@mediapipe/face_mesh". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
Ok, no problem. So I modified each import statement to be relative path to where I installed them locally, like:
`import './node_modules/@mediapipe/face_mesh'
But then I get this error: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
It seems that it wants a script but the documentation implies you're importing a folder(?) not an individual js file? For example, in ./node_modules/@mediapipe/face_mesh, there are several js files, text files, a package.json, etc. I can import ./node_modules/@mediapipe/face_mesh/face_mesh.js, but then I get another dependency error because face_mesh.js calls upon other js files in its same folder.
How am I supposed to import these libraries properly? I do not have the option to install via CDN instead, I have go the NPM/local hosting route because this is a chrome extension and all scripts must be local under the new Content Security Policy. Thanks!

To use NPM packages you need to build the code using webpack, rollup, or a similar bundler. Note that you can also just put the latest js from CDN into your extension and load it as any other script. You can do it every time you release a new extension automatically.
